# How can I compile a c++ file which depends on multiple 3rd party headers recursively

Tags: c++, gcc

I have a c++ file `test_arb.cpp`

```
#include "arb.h"

int main()
{
 //some code
}
```

I  run like this:

I found `arb` calls `flint` so I uncluded both arb and flint like this :

```
g++ -c -I"C:/Users\hp/Documents/Projects/arb" -I"C:\Users\hp\Documents\Projects" test_arb.cpp
```

Now I am stuck with error on [GMP](https://github.com/alisw/GMP) library:

> C:\Users\hp\Documents\Projects/flint/flint.h:20:10: fatal error:
> gmp.h: No such file or directory    20 | #include <gmp.h>

I am stuck on next call of "gmp.h". In GMP source it doesnt even have a "gmp.h". How so how do I proceed next?

I need a generic approach since there are more 3rd party libs which `flint` calls.

PS: I am on windows 10.

Comment: If `flint.h` is right under the directory `C:\Users\hp\Documents\Projects\flint`, then you should pass `-I"C:\Users\hp\Documents\Projects"` (notice the lack of `\flint` here) to gcc, because the include is `#include "flint/flint.h"` and not `#include "flint.h"`. Is this the case?

Comment: Thanks, mybad, got that part . now I am stuck on next call of "gmp.h". In [GMP](https://github.com/alisw/GMP) source it doesnt even have a "gmp.h". How so how do I proceed next? I will update the question,

Comment: You shouldn't be `#include`ing from the source repositories of your dependencies. These libraries are typically designed to be built and installed before use. Take a look at [the `INSTALL` file](https://github.com/alisw/GMP/blob/master/INSTALL) of GMP to see the instructions. You may also consider using a proper build system that does this for you if you don't absolutely have to invoke gcc by yourself.